# Need to sort dates and pull through earliest value and return data from a different cell

Tags: excel, indexing, match

[image: Find the earliest date in column E and return the company name from column B]

Hi all
I need to find a way of showing PEN LTD in G2 rather than DRINK LTD.

Column B is my customers

Column C is the earliest date we can service equipment

Column D is the different status for each customer relating to their service

I want to find all customers who have the status 'book in now!!' and I want to then find the earliest service date in Column C and pull the name of the company into G2.

Right now I can pull through a customer with the status "book in now!!" but I can't get it to pull through the customer with the earliest date. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data by the date from earliest to latest. Then the Index Match will return the match for the earliest date when there are multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(1/(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(1/((D24:D28=D30)*(C24:C28))),1)=C24:C28)),B24:B28)
```

The `AGGREGATE` function returns the earliest date where there is a match with the contents of `D30` in your `D` range.  We then use a feature of the `LOOKUP` function to return the match in column B

[image]